# AJAX call - input variable suddenly not submitted anymore

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I generate modal form content via AJAX and allow users to update several input / select fields before submitting their revised data to the database. This code  works fine across many forms on my website, but since today, ONE specific input field is not being submitted via AJAX anymore, while all other input fields in the same form work without a problem.

Input field `dataHolidex` holds a 5 digit letter code (no number, no symbols, just plain latin characters) I need for selecting the correct database, but it seems the input value is not being picked up before the AJAX call. Chrome Debug says that the submitted `$_POST['Holidex']` is empty, even though the corresponding input field is populated correctly, suggesting that there is a problem when handing over the input field value to the AJAX $_POST call.

Form content (input field has value)

```
  <div class=\"col-md-4\">
    <!-- Holidex -->
    <label>Holidex:</label>
    <div class=\"input-group\">
        <span class=\"input-group-addon\"><i class=\"fa fa-database\"></i></span>
        <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"$holidex\" id=\"dataHolidex\" name=\"dataHolidex\" size=\"\" />
    </div>
    <!-- /.holidex code -->
  </div>
```

AJAX call to update the database with the new form values

```
var holidex_code = document.getElementById("dataHolidex").value;

$.ajax({
    url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true, 
    data: {
        action:"update_email",
        Holidex: holidex_code,
        CRS:$("#dataCRS").val(),
        Arrival:$("#dataArr").val(),
        Departure:$("#dataDep").val(),
        Room:$("#dataRoom").val(),
        GuestNat:$("#dataNat").val(),
        GuestTitle:$("#dataGuestTitle").val(),
        GuestFN:$("#dataGuestFN").val(),
        GuestLN:$("#dataGuestLN").val(),
        MBR_Lvl:$("#dataMBRlvl").val(),
        Email:$("#dataEmail").val()
    }, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
    dataType: "html",

    success: function(data) {
        $('#poststay_output').html(data);
        drawVisualization();   
    },

    error: function(data) {
    console.log(err);
    }
});
```

The code is correct and works well all over the site, I didnt make any changes to the server nor am I aware of any upgrades, literally NOTHING has changed. Anyone has any clue what this could be?

EDIT:
removed the jQuery code for grabbing the `Holidex` variable and replaced it with pure JavaScript. Result is the same, the variable is empty when handed over...

Comment: is the above markup a js template or html?

Comment: The `<input>` field is generate via PHP, hence HTML. The AJAX call is done via Javascript on the specific PHP/HTML site.

Comment: can you add a console statement and see what is the value of $("#dataHolidex").val() before sending the ajax call

Comment: And that $.ajax call is triggered ... how?

Comment: `$("#dataHolidex").val()` has sample value `ABCDE` which is correct. The problem is that the variable is not handed over correctly to the AJAX call, hence when the call is received, it is shown as `empty`. The call is triggered via the click of an update button on the modal.

Comment: To eliminate one possible variable, please try using plain JavaScript to collect the values *i.e.* use `document.getElementById("dataHolidex").value` instead of `$("#dataHolidex").val()`. If that still fails, we can rule out a problem with *your* jQuery.

Comment: Did that, but still the same result. I have double and triple checked the `dataHolidex` value and its nothing more than `ABCDE`, I dont understand why this is happening -.-

Comment: Why not use `$("#dataholidex").val();` instead of `holidex_code`

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I just managed to solve this by changing the input field name from `dataHolidex` to `dataPropertyCode` and it works. Perhaps something wrong the server? A previous submission stuck somewhere maybe?